# How do I invoke a method when my NSComboBoxCell text has been edited?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Please note it is not a NSComboBox, but a NSComboBoxCell.

Also, note I'm on Leopard (OSX 10.5).

So far I've been able only to invoke a method when another item is selected in the NSComboBoxCell items menu, but not when the text is edited, by manually typing it.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `NSControlTextDidChangeNotification` send by concrete NSControl subclasses. You can subscribe to that. It might be easier and cleaner to implement the corresponding notification method in the delegate.

To do that, you connect the delegate outlet of the `NSComboBox` to some object in the XIB file. Then you override `- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj;` there. This notification exists since 10.0, I didn't test on 10.5, though.

Comment: Is there a delegate method invoked when the NSComboBox popup is selected, so I can populate the completions list when the combo box is clicked instead? thanks